# Find the number of 5 digit numbers using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - in which first k digits are not only o to k

Tags: algorithm

The question is to find the number of 5 digits numbers possible using 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 as digits, in which the set of first k numbers (k is natural number, and k < 5) is not equal to set of numbers from 1 to k.

Clarification - Order of elements of set does not matter. {1, 2} is same as {2, 1} ie {1, 2} = {2, 1}.

For example, in 54213 is a correct number and it will be counted - as

- k = 1, we get {5}, and {5} != {1}
- k = 2, {5, 4} != {1, 2}
- k = 3, {5, 4, 2} != {1, 2, 3}
- k = 4, {5, 4, 2, 1} != {1, 2, 3, 4}

Also, the number 13245 is not valid, as for k = 1, {1} = {1}.

**Bonus question**, find the number of 6 digit possible numbers with same criteria and digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, & 6.

**Edit** - I am sorry for not having followed this up with my method. I have added my solution below.

Comment: I do wish there were a close reason for homework questions that show absolutely no effort on the part of the OP.

Comment: Instead of adding bonus question, it would be better if you had shown your effort.

Comment: This was a question asked in Zonal Informatics Olympiad - just the language was different. I have attempted it and my solution is 71. I am just not sure about it, and would love to see someone else's attempt at it. I'll get to learn something new, and maybe a faster method! :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you can add one ;)

Comment: Added my solution to the question. Thanks a lot, for your input, people! :) @GordonLinoff

Comment: There's a typo in `3 2 1 _ _ = 1`. Have a look at the wording and the first [FORMULA](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,1,3,13,71&go=Search) attributed to Bowen. (Consider answering your own question.)

Comment: @BrahmnoorSingh . . . Welcome to StackOverflow.  As you can see, the community is a bit sensitive to certain things, such as questions that look like they were taken directly from homework.  If you had introduced this as a question from a competition along with your suggested solution, the question would have been much better received.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff. I do understand that when someone asks a question - he should also state his method - otherwise it looks quite like a homework question. I am relatively new to Stack Overflow, but in the future, I will make sure that I include my progress towards the solution too. :) Thanks again, and have a nice day ahead! :)

Comment: @greybeard, Thanks a lot for pointing out that typo. I have corrected it, and I have moved the solution to the answers section. I am taking a look at that link, but there are certain aspects that I haven't understood there.

Answer (score 1):

Number of 5 digit numbers possible with the given digits = 5! = 120

Let's consider the digits that are NOT to be formed.

1. 1 _ _ _ _ = 4! = 24 (As clearly, k = 1 {1} = {1})
2. 2 1 _ _ _ = 3! = 6 (As clearly, k = 2 {2, 1} = {1, 2}, also we will not consider 1 2 _ _ _ as it has already been included in 1)
3. 2 3 1 _ _ = 2! = 2
4. 3 1 2 _ _ = 2! = 2
5. 3 2 1 _ _ = 2! = 2
6. 2 3 4 1 _ = 1
7. 2 4 1 3 _ = 1
8. 2 4 3 1 _ = 1
9. 3 1 4 2 _ = 1
10. 3 2 4 1 _ = 1
11. 3 4 2 1 _ = 1
12. 3 4 1 2 _ = 1
13. 4 - - - _ = 3! x 1 = 6 (Where dashes can be filled by 1, 2, 3)

Total number = 49

But there are the NOT cases. Now, the cases required = 120 - 49 = 71.

For 6, I used recursion, as clearly in case of 5, the series (for the numbers that are NOT to be formed) is

1 x 4!  + 1 x 3! + 3 x 2! + 13 x 1! (where 1, 1, 3, and 13 is the solution for the given condition for 1 digit, 2, digit, 3 digit and 4 digit respectively)

{ie, for 1 digit number using only 1, where k < 1, k is natural, number of possible digits - 1 (1). For 2 digit number using only 1, 2, where k < 2, the number of possible digits - 1 (21). For 3, it is 321, 231, 312 and so on)

Hence, for 6, the series becomes

1 x 5! + 1 x 4! + 3 x 3! + 13 x 2! + 71 (where 71 is the solution for given condition of 5 digits)

= 259

ie. for 6, the solutions = 6! - 259 = 461